# Record with List of Records Unit Test Failing

Tags: unit-testing, f#

I have the following records:

```
namespace FunctionalInnovate.Domain

module Voting=

open System

    type Vote = {
        VoteId : int
        SuggestionId : int
        VotePreference : int
    }

    type Suggestion = {
        SuggetionId : int
        SuggestionText : string
    }

    type User = {
        UserId : int
        Votes : Vote list
    }
```

From these records, I have created the following Unit Test:

```
module ``Voting Tests``

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit
open FunctionalInnovate.Domain.Voting

[<Test>] 
let``Get Vote from given SuggestionId``()=

    let votePreference = 1 

    let vote1 = { VoteId = 1; SuggestionId = 34; VotePreference = votePreference }
    let vote2 = { VoteId = 2; SuggestionId = 654; VotePreference = votePreference}

    let votes = [ vote1; vote2; ]

    let user = {UserId = 321; Votes = votes}

    Assert.IsTrue(true) |> ignore
```

I've just changed the Assert statement to something simple at this point as it keeps failing at present. Using ReSharper, when I run the test I get an error. Upon investigation, it appears to be a problem with the List of Votes being assigned to the Votes type within my `user` declaration. What I find strange though is that if I load all of the types into FSI and then load each line of the test in turn, it works without any errors.

Anyone got any ideas as to why the unit test is failing?

The error ReSharper Test Runner is producing is:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void User..ctor(Int32, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<Vote>)'.

   at Voting Tests.Get Vote from given SuggestionId()
```

Comment: My guess - somehow the wrong version of `FSharp.Core` is being referenced

Comment: Where is the record type `{ UserId : int; Votes : Vote list }` is defined?

Comment: Certainly `FSharp.Core.dll` issue. Try adding binding redirect to the unit test project: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/

Comment: Sorry @Petr, fixed the typo now :). Thanks John and Tomas, I'll give it a try when I get to work

Comment: @TomasPetricek / John Palmer...thanks for your help. It was an older version of FSharp.Core.dll in my UnitTest project. I went into NuGet Package Manager, updated it to the latest version and all is now working. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Tomas Petricek and @John Palmer's advice, it was an issue with my ''FSharp.Core.dll'' version.

**The version of this DLL in my UnitTest project was much older than what was in my Domain project.**

All I did to fix it was going into NuGet Package Manager and update that specific package. Upon running my tests again, everything was green and healthy.